# What are the performance differences of using 'static vs 'a?

Tags: performance, memory, rust, lifetime

Considering the below functions, what performance differences would you expect?

```
pub fn foo<'a>(data: Request) -> Response<'a> {
    //
}
```

vs.

```
pub fn foo(data: Request) -> Response<'static> {
    //
}
```

Would the `Response` having a lifetime of `'static` keep every `Response` in memory for the life of the program?

How long would `'a` be held in memory vs `'static`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two functions will generate identical machine code. Lifetimes are removed during compilation. If your program checks out, they have no further meaning.

In particular, it's wrong to think of lifetimes as "this is held in memory this long". Lifetimes are all about "this stays alive long enough". It's a subtle distinction, but the key thing to remember is that lifetimes are *descriptive*, not *prescriptive*. Giving something a lifetime doesn't mean it stays alive for a certain duration; either it is alive for the necessary duration for other reasons (e.g. a global variable can be referenced with `'static`), or the program won't compile.

Second, the lifetimes in your snippets have no immediate effect at all. They're just parameters to the `Response` struct. It is up to that struct to decide what to do with the lifetime. Does it internally hold a reference to something with this lifetime? Is it just forwarded to a `PhantomData` used to associate the response with some connection?

Third, given the way the function is defined (with the lifetime parameter only used in the return type), there is no difference in the requirements on the implementation. Because the lifetime here is chosen by the *caller*, the function must be prepared to fulfill the `'static` lifetime anyway. All this does is make the usage more annoying for the caller.

So to sum up:

- Lifetimes don't work that way.
- The first version is not useful.